# Regex: Count matches from list of words

Tags: regex, list, count, cpu-word

I'm trying to get the right syntax for getting the number of matches from list of words
example:

List: (US,UK,Greece,Germany,Nigeria,Brazil)

The text is: "Cake returns put Brazil Welcome Stack to between paragraphs Argentina Overflow UK"

I would like to know how many words from the list above appear in this text with a regex pattern.
Alternative, I would like to know if there more than 1 match from the list in the text

Is it possible to do that with Regex?

Answer (score 2):

In Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> countries = re.compile(r"\b(?:US|UK|Greece|Germany|Nigeria|Brazil)\b")
>>> text = "Cake returns put Brazil Welcome Stack to between paragraphs Argentina Overflow UK"
>>> len(countries.findall(text))
2
```

**Explanation:**

```
\b      # Word boundary (start of word)
(?:     # Match either...
 US     # US
|       # or
 UK     # UK
|       # or
 Greece # Greece (etc.)
)       # End of alternation
\b      # Word boundary (end of word)
```